# How can I use one app instance for all my e2e tests?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I'm working in a nestjs project that is organized into separate modules. Each module has it's own e2e test. Inside each of these tests an instance of the application is created in the `beforeAll()` method. Like this

```
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule,
      ],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
```

At the end of the test the `app.close()` is called tearing down the app.

Is there a way I can use the same app for all of my tests and then just shut the app down at the end? Creating and tearing down the entire app for each test makes the e2e tests take a long time. Also I'm running into Async timeout errors.

Comment: Don't build the whole app for e2e tests, use only modules (and respective dependencies) which you are testing in a single test suite.

Comment: So I added two modules instead of the entire `AppModule` and I'm still getting Async Timeout errors. All I added was a one very small custom module and `TypeOrm.forRoot()`

Answer (score 3):

After many trials, I found out that this was impossible because:

> [Every test runs in its own environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array)

Let me elaborate:

**1.  You cannot setup app instance in [globalSetup](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globalsetup-string)**, because:

> Note: Any global variables that are defined through globalSetup can only be read in globalTeardown. You cannot retrieve globals defined here in your test suites.

Which means that you cannot use one `global.app` variable across test cases. If you cannot share `global.app` variable, then you cannot use `request(app.getHttpServer())`, which is essential for e2e tests.

**2. You can setup app instance in `setupFiles` or `setupFilesAfterEnv` but these files will be running per each test case.** This is clearly against the intention

> Each setupFile will be run once per test file. Since every test runs in its own environment, these scripts will be executed in the testing environment before executing setupFilesAfterEnv and before the test code itself.

The document doesn't say `setupFileAfterEnv` will be run per test file. So I tried, but unfortunately, it ran per test file.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a script to [`globalSetup`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globalsetup-string) that creates an app that listens on a specific port. Then, to make request to the app in the test, create an agent that uses the same port.

1. Add a global variable in your Jest configuration

```
import type { Config } from 'jest';

export default async (): Promise<Config> => {
  return {
    ...
    globals: {
      APP_PORT: findOpenTCPPort(), // Implement this logic yourself, or hardcode it
    },
    globalSetup: '<rootDir>/e2e.globalSetup.ts',
    globalTeardown: '<rootDir>/e2e.globalTeardown.ts',
  };
};
```

2. Add typings for this new global variable inside a `.d.ts` file. I named my file as `e2e.types.d.ts` and put it inside a `types` directory.

```
declare global {
  const APP_PORT: number;
}

export {};
```

3. Make sure the `*.d.ts` is read by the TypeScript server

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types/", "./types"]
    }
}
```

4. Add the `e2e.globalSetup.ts` script that creates the NestJS app.

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';

module.exports = async function globalSetup(_, projectConfig) {
  const module = Test.createTestingModule({ ... })
  const moduleRef = await module.compile();
  const app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
  await app.init();
  await app.listen(projectConfig.globals.APP_PORT);
  globalThis.APP = app;
};
```

5. Add a `e2e.globalTeardown.ts` that shuts down the app

```
module.exports = async function globalTeardown() {
  await globalThis.APP.close();
  process.exit();
};
```

6. Create the supertest agent in your tests

```
...
import request from 'supertest';
const agent = request(`http://localhost:${APP_PORT}`);

describe('[POST] /some/endpoint', () => {
  it('400 - Missing parameters', async () => {
    const response = await agent.post('/some/endpoint').send({});
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  });
});
```